# Откуда берутся лишние биты в представлении unsigned long long?

Tags: c, типы-данных, системы-счисления

Разрабатывал спецификатор `%x` с помощью двоичных тетрад. После чего решил расширить функционал до `%llx`. Но не тут то было! По каким-то причинам программа работала не верно.

Решил рассмотреть побитовое представление числа в формате `long long unsigned`. В итоге обнаружил, что, например `32` бит числа `1` равен 1. Почему так?

Собственно сабж:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int checkbit(unsigned long long value, int position)
{
    return ((value & (1 << position)) != 0);
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned long long num = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned long long) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
        printf("%d = %d\n", i, checkbit(num, i));

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
0 = 1
1 = 0
2 = 0
3 = 0
4 = 0
5 = 0
6 = 0
7 = 0
8 = 0
9 = 0
10 = 0
11 = 0
12 = 0
13 = 0
14 = 0
15 = 0
16 = 0
17 = 0
18 = 0
19 = 0
20 = 0
21 = 0
22 = 0
23 = 0
24 = 0
25 = 0
26 = 0
27 = 0
28 = 0
29 = 0
30 = 0
31 = 0
32 = 1
33 = 0
34 = 0
35 = 0
36 = 0
37 = 0
38 = 0
39 = 0
40 = 0
41 = 0
42 = 0
43 = 0
44 = 0
45 = 0
46 = 0
47 = 0
48 = 0
49 = 0
50 = 0
51 = 0
52 = 0
53 = 0
54 = 0
55 = 0
56 = 0
57 = 0
58 = 0
59 = 0
60 = 0
61 = 0
62 = 0
63 = 0
```

Comment: В том числе именно по этой причине в качестве рекомендуемого способа проверки значения бита можно предложить `(value >> position) & 1`. Чем меньше в выражении зависимостей от конкретных типов аргументов - тем лучше.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Всё дело в строке `1 << position`
Литерал `1` имеет тип `int`, который, на вашей платформе имеет размер, меньший, чем `unsigned long long`, и при `position >= sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` результат сдвига не может быть представлен в типе `int`, поэтому возникает неопределенное поведение.

Из стандарта C++14:

> Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2^E2 is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Из стандарта C11:

> If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Исправление: `(1ull << position)`

Comment: Приведённая вами цитата является цитатой из стандарта языка C++. В C требования для сдвига знаковых величин влево немного более строгие: "If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2^E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.".

Comment: @wololo пока искал документ, забыл, что вопрос по C. Добавил в ответ и цитату из стандарта C11. Спасибо.